# Delete the first char of a string and append to end of string

Tags: c#

I need to get the first char of this string:

```
String s = "X-4711";
```

And put it after the number with an ';' , like: 4711;X.

I already tried it with:

```
String x = s.Split("-")[1] + ";" + s.Split("-")[0];
```

then I get it, but can I do it better or is this the only possible way?

Comment: First of all, it is `Split` not `split`. C# is case sensitive. Second, your solution is quite simple, understandable and efficient I think based on your input. What do you mean by _better_ exactly? Of course you can find another ways but your solution is good in my opinion. If you think this is not good enough, explain _why_ at least.

Comment: `String result = s.Substring(2) + ";" + s.Substring(0, 1);`

Comment: I don't like this double `Split` i want it a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var items = s.Split ("-");
string x = String.Format ("{0};{1}", items[1], items[0]);
```

At most this makes it a little more readable and a micro-optimisation of only having to split once.

EDIT :

As some of the comments have pointed out, if you are using C#6 you can make use of [String Interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) to format the string. It does the exact same thing, only looks a little better.

```
var items = s.Split ("-");
string x = $"{items[1]};{items[0])}";
```

Comment: Upvoted this one, I would only add a minor change to the use of string.format: String.Format($"{items[1]};{items[0]}");

Comment: @PedroG.Dias assuming OP is using c#6 ofc.

Comment: This one looks way much better, thank you.
I did not like mine, because of the "+" and "+"

Comment: Or maybe `string x = string.Format( "{0};{1}", s.Substring(2), s[0] );`

Comment: @PedroG.Dias Isn't `$"{items[1]};{items[0]}"` sufficient? The extra `string.Format` is unnecessary when using string interpolation.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what performance you are looking for small `string` operations, your code is well written and satisfy your needs.

One minor thing you might consider is removing additional split performed on input string.

```
var subs = s.Split ("-");
String.Format ("{0};{1}", subs [1], subs [0]);
```

If you are looking single liner (crazy programmer), this might help.

```
string.Join(";", s.Split('-').Reverse())
```

Answer (score 2):

String.Substring: Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position and has a specified length.

```
string sub = input.Substring(0, 1);
string restStr = input.Substring(2, input.length-2);
// string restStr = input.Substring(2); Can also use this instead of above line
string madeStr = restStr + ";" + sub;
```

You call the Substring method to extract a substring from a string that begins at a specified character position and ends before the end of the string. The starting character position is a zero-based; in other words, the first character in the string is at index 0, not index 1. To extract a substring that begins at a specified character position and continues to the end of the string, call the Substring method.

Comment: `input.Substring(2)` does the same - without `length - 2`.

Comment: yes see the commented line in the code. Thats what I have written